# Setting a Recurring Event using Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: iphone, android, appcelerator, alarm, appcelerator-mobile

I've got an app I'm building using Appcelerator Titanium that will be a combination alarm clock/url fetcher. The part I'm having problem with is that I need to be able to set a time for the app to go fetch the url and then perform actions as necessary (in this case alert the user if data that should be entered in a time system has been entered). I also want it to do this every day (or every week day) at the prescribed time, and I want it to not have to be 'launched' every time. I'd rather it come up and run as a service, or at least run as a service when sent to the background. I'm most focused on the iPhone, but I've got a few Android users that would like it as well.

Is it even possible to have an Appcelerator app hooked into the system like that? If so, are there any tutorials or examples? I can't even find an alarm clock example, which scares me a bit.

Comment: for iPhone will you be using push notifications?

Comment: I would like to use a push notification, a badge and/or a pop up. Basically whatever I can get to work!

Comment: android apps typically run in the background from the get go but to get a closed iPhone app not running in the background you will need push notifications

Answer (score 0):

I think that localNotifications should work for you.

there is a sample in the [bg.js](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/bg.js) file included in the kitchenSink.

It is also helpful to know that all of the keys/properties available to you are documented [here in the source code.](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/iphone/Classes/TiAppiOSProxy.m#L69)

Answer (score 0):

This guy has a nice alarm module written for android. 
https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager